# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta (find) dentro de un Array?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección con 10 documentos, y cada uno de ellos tiene un arreglo. Se ve de esta manera:

```
"exist" : 66658,
"almacenes" : [ 
    {
        "bodegaI" : "disp",
        "prod_st" : "active",
        "ult_venta" : "2022-11-23",
        "factura_uv" : 154368244,
        "precio" : 8
    }, 
    {
        "bodegaII" : "disp",
        "prod_st" : "active",
        "ult_venta" : "2022-04-18",
        "factura_uv" : 879624124,
        "precio" : 8
    }, 
    {
        "bodegaIII" : "disp",
        "prod_st" : "active",
        "ult_venta" : "2021-07-05",
        "factura_uv" : 357846988,
        "precio" : 8
    }
],
```

Y así como ese, tengo 10 documentos más. Lo que quiero hacer es poder ejecutar un comando que me muestre solo los productos que estén disponibles (Por ej: En la bodegaI).

He intentado con `db.nameCollection.find({filename:"___"});`, pero no aplica para este.

Mi versión de Mongo: `5.0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería funcionarte:

```
const findDocByDisp = async () => {
     const mydoc = await db.nameCollection.find({ 'almacenes.bodegaI': 'disp'}, (err, d) => {}).catch();
     console.log(mydoc);
     return myDoc;
}
```

También puedes pasarle como parámetros directamente lo que necesitas buscar:

```
const findDoc = async (subItem: string, value: string | number) => {
     const mydoc = await db.nameCollection.find({ `almacenes.${subItem}`: value}, (err, d) => {}).catch();
     console.log(mydoc)
     return mydoc;
}
```

Con esta segunda función no solo serías capaz de buscar por bodegaI, sino por cualquier elemento como prod_st, precio o bodegaI.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
const findDoc = async (subItem: string, value: string | number) => {
     const mydoc = await db.nameCollection.find({`almacenes.${subItem}`: value}, (err, d) => {}).catch();
     console.log(mydoc)
     return mydoc;
}

const documento_con_bodegaI_disp = findDoc('bodegaI', 'disp');
console.log(documento_con_bodegaI_disp);

const documento_con_ult_venta = findDoc('ult_venta', '2022-11-23');
console.log(documento_con_ult_venta);
```

Respuesta válida si usas Typescript y Mongoose.

Comment: Esto: `find({almacenes.bodegaI: 'disp'} ... ` falla. No puedes usar notación de punto para filtros sin encerrar la ruta entre comillas: `find({ 'almacenes.bodegaI':, 'disp'} ... `.

Comment: Cierto Mauricio, puse la respuesta de memoria, gracias por la correción, respuesta editada ;)